# How to transform an Object into Json on Ionic?

Tags: json, object, ionic3

I have the following object. How to turn this object into a Json?

```
 initializeItems() {
   this.items = [
 {id: '1', nome:'Abaéte', rua:'Moacir', cidade:'Capão da Canoa', bairro:'Centro', numero:'396', ano:'1964', aptos:'55', adm:'Adsel', zelador:'Hugo', contato1:'(51) 0 0000 - 0000', contato2: '(51) 0000 - 0000', imagem:'assets/img/Abaete-min.jpg'},
];
```

And I want to turn it into Json

```
{
"predios" : {
    "adm" : "Adsel",
    "ano" : 1964,
    "aptos" : 55,
    "bairro" : "Centro",
    "cidade" : "Capão da Canoa",
    "contato1" : "(51) 9 0000 - 0000",
    "contato2" : "(51) 0000 - 0000",
    "id" : 1,
    "imagem" : "Abaete-min.JPG",
    "nome" : "Abaéte",
    "numero" : 396,
    "rua" : "Moacir",
    "zelador" : "Hugo"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
JSON.stringify()
```

```js
function initialize() {
var items = [{id: '1', nome:'Abaéte', rua:'Moacir', cidade:'Capão da Canoa', bairro:'Centro', numero:'396', ano:'1964', aptos:'55', adm:'Adsel', zelador:'Hugo', contato1:'(51) 0 0000 - 0000', contato2: '(51) 0000 - 0000', imagem:'assets/img/Abaete-min.jpg'}];

var jsonObject = {"predios": items[0]}

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
} 
initialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that,

1. Get the first element of `this.items` as it is an array
2. Assign the first element within an object

`var prediosJsonObj = {"predios": this.items[0]}`

---

To clear up any confusion, JSON supports 2 types of data structure:

- Collection of name/value pairs (Object, dictionary, etc)
- Ordered list of values (Array, list, etc)

`this.items` is already considered JSON with an array structure. What you wanted is how to transform JSON array to a JSON object.

https://www.w3resource.com/JSON/structures.php